# How to hide stripe secret key using serverless lambda function deploying to Netlify

Tags: lambda, stripe-payments, netlify

I am using a serverless lambda function to run Stripe payments. It runs fine in local host, but when i deploy to netlify it doesnt work. I get a 400 error.

I followed this tutorial, but then changed the charge.js to use dotenv
https://mitchgavan.com/react-serverless-shop/

In my server function i have the following…

```
require(‘dotenv’).config()
const stripe = require(‘stripe’)(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

i have a .env file with the SK in there, and this works when running on localhost. But it doesnt work when i deploy.

I have added the SK in Netlify’s dashboard

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY      sk_test_opK…sIKZ
```

But it doesnt work for me, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the dependency `dotenv` does not exist when the lambda function executes, because you did not package it into your function.

When using Netlify's dashboard to store the private key, you won't have a `.env`. This is good news, because you don't want to store that key in your repository. This is only needed in your case for local development.

- Remove `require('dotenv').config()` from your function, because it is not needed in this case on Netlify, because `process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` will exist on Netlify at the time the function executes.
- Add the key during local development with a different process (maybe using `cross-env` at the command line instead)